# Freeze issues on mac when operated directly

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I am facing a very strange problem, I am executing my project executable in MAC terminal window, the process will halt after some time, but when I remotely access that machine and follow same procedure it will complete the process successfully. I don't know the reason why it can't work when I tried executing directly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checkt the rights management? 
Maybe you're trying to do something that the OS thinks it has to prevent.

Indeed this is strange. Maybe try to "repair" the "access privileges" and "volumes" in the "Disk-Utility".
Often this fixes a lot of problems.